# Cannot get net time to work across domains on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface

I have been running this command on Windows XP without issue:

net time \servername.domain /SET

Where the domain is not my current domain.

On Windows 7 I am receiving a pop-up:

> **net1.exe - System Error** 
> The program can't start because NWPROVAU.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

On the command prompt:

> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

I need this to synchronize the clock between one system on the domain, and one not on it.  Alternative options would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Net Time has been replaced and you should use w32tm instead.

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist: peers /syncfromflags:manual /update
```

Replace ***peers*** with the fqdn or ip-addresses of the PDC emulator (and\or other ntp time source(s) use a space as a delimitter). [Full details here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784800(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: Perfect!  One thing, there should be no space between the : and the first peer.